# Tkinter Check if Window with Entry has been clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on creating a 2D Graphics Framework for Python called [goopylib](https://github.com/BhavyeMathur/goopylib) built on top of Tkinter and I wanted to implement a function that would check whether an entry widget was clicked.

Now the default way of doing this in Tkinter is to bind the entry object `<Button>` event to a function and check if it was clicked. But I require something different in my case.

In goopy, the window checks whether it was clicked and basically returns the position of the mouse click. This can then be used in an `is_clicked(mouse_pos)` function implemented in every object. This works great for every object, Rectangles, Circles, Images, Buttons, etc.

But the problem arises with Entries. For some reason, the window doesn't register a click when I have clicked the Entry or really any mouse event. It doesn't register a moving mouse over the Entry etc. This means that if indeed the user has the clicked the Entry, the mouse click hasn't been registered in the Window.

The full code is in this link: https://github.com/BhavyeMathur/goopylib/tree/master/goopylib. The GraphWin class is the toplevel window and the objects/Entry class is the Entry. I have also tried shortening a bit of the code that I thought might be the problem:

The Entry draw function (shortened)

```py
def _draw(canvas, ...)
    p = (55, 55)
    x, y = canvas.to_screen(p[0], p[1])
    frm = tkFrame(canvas.master)  # Equivalent of tk.Frame

    self.entry = tkEntry(frm, width=10, textvariable=self.text, selectbackground=self.select_colour)
    self.entry.pack()

    return canvas.create_window(x, y, window=frm)
```

The Window `__init__` function (shortened). The window inherits from `tk.Canvas`.

```
class GraphWin(tkCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        master = tkToplevel(_root)  # Actually creating the window
        master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)

        tkCanvas.__init__(self, master, width=110, height=110)

        self.pack()

        # Here we bind the mouse events

        self.bind("<Button-1>", self._on_left_click)

    def _on_left_click(e):   # This isn't called when the Entry has been clicked
        self.mouse_left_click = e.x, e.y
        self.last_mouse_event = self.trans.world(e.x, e.y)
```

If you want to try the entire code with goopy, you will need to install it like:

```
pip install goopylib
```

and run this code:

```py
from goopylib.imports import *

window = GraphWin("Test Window", width=110, height=110)
e = Entry(Point(55, 55), text_width=10).draw(window)

while True:

    mouse_pos = window.check_left_mouse_click()  # Get's the last mouse click position 
    if mouse_pos is not None:
        print(mouse_pos, e.get_width(), e.get_height())

    if e.is_clicked(mouse_pos):
        print(1)
    window.update_win()   # Updates the window
```

Comment: `tk.Entry` registers clicks, there must be something else.

Comment: Yes, I think the Entry is registering the click, but not the window.